# How do I get a value from the next record with a WHERE condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

I've created an SQL View using the Management Studio.  The view joins a couple of tables together and is accessed by my MVC Application.  The tables are related to car rental.  One table holds the car details whilst the other table holds booking information, these are joined using the view.

The view works without a problem but I've been asked to also add a column that shows the next immediate booking that the car has.  That means that I need a column to show the next booking start date where the cars Id matches.

**Table: Cars**

- [Id]
- [Registration]
- [Make]
- [Model]

**Table: Bookings**

- [Id]
- [BookingStartDate]
- [BookingEndDate]
- [CarId]

**View: CarBookings**

```
SELECT  [C].[Id],
        [C].[Registration],
        [C].[Make],
        [C].[Model],
        [B].[BookingStartDate],
        [B].[BookingEndDate]

  FROM [Cars] AS C INNER JOIN [Bookings] AS B ON C.Id = B.CarId
```

How can I add a column to my view that will show the immediate next booking that a car has? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any logic present for determining which first booking is being shown.  Your current view would show _all_ bookings for a given car.  Some sample data would help here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the next immediate booking"? How does that logic work? Where is that stored? What data do you have available in that case? Your current sql should just retrieve all the coherent instances between your cars and bookings, meaning you will also by default get the "next immediate booking" by default, assuming it's stored in the booking table?

Comment: From the question it seems that you need the first booking at or after the current datetime?  If so, then you could use a [TOP or a LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) with an order by.  But that syntax is rather database dependant. So you might want to add a tag for the type of database you need this for.

Comment: Do you want to show car info and the next upcoming booking only? (As mentioned your current query currently show all bookings, old and new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim mentioned in comments, your query alreadi gives you all bookings, but if you need in another column, then may be `lead()` is what you need ?

```
SELECT  C.Id,
B.BookingStartDate,
B.BookingEndDate,
lead(BookingStartDate) over(partition by C.Id order by B.BookingEndDate) nextdt
FROM Cars AS C INNER JOIN Bookings AS B ON C.Id = B.CarId
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `LEAD()` (sql server 2012 onwards)

```
select c.*, b.BookingStartDate, b.BookingEndDate,
       lead(bookingstartdate) over (partition by carid order by BookingStartDate) as nextbooking
from cars c
inner join bookings b
on c.id = b.carid
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `LEAD` (if it's available), but I think you'll need to restrict your query somehow to only return the latest booking record (it currently returns everything).

Comment: I think so also, just missed comma after `b.BookingEndDate` and you mean `BookingEndDate` instead of `date` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Question unclear on this, so providing the holistic view

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query which should generate the results you want.  In a CTE I use a pivot query to turn out the most recent, and second most recent, booking record for each `CarId`.  Then, we join this CTE to the `Car` table in a similar way which you were already doing.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        CarId,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN BookingStartDate END) AS BookingStartDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN BookingEndDate   END) AS BookingEndDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN BookingStartDate END) AS NextBookingStartDate,
        MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN BookingEndDate   END) AS NextBookingEndDate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT CarId, BookingStartDate, BookingEndDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarId ORDER BY BookingStartDate DESC) rn
        FROM Bookings
    ) t
    WHERE rn <= 2
    GROUP BY CarId
)

SELECT
    c.Id,
    c.Registration,
    c.Make,
    c.Model,
    b.BookingStartDate,
    b.BookingEndDate,
    b.NextBookingStartDate,
    b.NextBookingEndDate
FROM Cars c
INNER JOIN cte b
    ON c.Id = b.CarId;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the existing view does what you want (which is all combinations of cars and bookings except cars without bookings since you used inner join),
and you just want to project the "next" order which I assume references to the current date time,

you can add a left join to a query which pulls the "next" booking per car and create a column which conditions it when it matches the next record.

Left join logic:

1. Get all future bookings per car (that's the where filter)
2. Take the next one (min booking-time).
3. Join - on booking date and carId (now if there will be two identical
   bookings per car, you will get both as next match, since join the
   condition will apply to both).

   ```
   select 
   a.* , 
   b.* ,
   case when c.carId is not null then 1 else 0 end as IsNext
   from cars a
   inner join bookings b
       on a.id = b.carid
   left join (select carid , min(bookingStartDate) bookingStartDate from bookings where bookingStartDate > now() group by carid) c
       on b.carId = c.carId
       and b.bookingStartDate = c.bookingStartDate
   ```

Comment: comment: that answer is postgres syntax since you didn't specify which db you are using. if it's sql server - replace now() with GETDATE()

Answer (score -1):

Below Query will give upcoming all Booking's for a particular car. If you want next one only then you should go with Row_number.

```
SELECT  [C].[Id],
        [C].[Registration],
        [C].[Make],
        [C].[Model],
        [B].[BookingStartDate],
        [B].[BookingEndDate]

  FROM [Cars] AS C 
  INNER JOIN [Bookings] AS B ON C.Id = B.CarId
  WHERE [B].[BookingStartDate] >= GETDATE()
  ORDER BY [B].[BookingStartDate]
```